# Fishpig authentication not working on Magento 2

Tags: composer-php, magento2, fishpig

I'm in the process of installing Fishpig to my Magneto 2 installation via the composer. I'm on Magneto v 2.3.3 with Ubuntu 18 and PHP 7.3.14

Im following their installation guideline:

- https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/root/installation/#composer

My problem is that it require authentication.

[image]

I followed the guidelines of Github and created my own personal access token to use as password. But no matter what value I use for the Username I stil get "Invalid credentials" 
I have tried my Github username, my email, my magento 2 admin username. What am I missing?

- https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fishpig/magento2-wordpress-integration-root is a premium extension offered by https://fishpig.co.uk/ and is retrieved from the private FishPig repo.

You can generate access details for this at https://fishpig.co.uk/downloads